# Stretch UIView over multiple UICollectionViewCells in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIScrollview with a UICollectionview in it which has multiple custom UICollectionViewCells.

What a I want is to stretch a UIView over multiple cells.

I tried to use: `cell.clipToBounds = NO;` which is working but when I scroll to left and scroll back the expanded part of the UIView is being cut off again.

I guess it has something to do with dequeuing of the cells which aren't used. Can I assign the expanded part to the new cell so that it won't get deleted or sth?

I had a former problem where Cells got duplicated therefor I had overwritten the method `prepareForReuse` of my custom UICollectionViewCell-Class.

```
-(void)prepareForReuse 
{ 
   for(id aView in [self.contentView subviews]) 
   {
     if ([aView isKindOfClass:[MyCustomUIView class]])
     {
       [aView removeFromSuperview];
     }
   }
}
```

Any advice and help will be thankfully appreciated.

Comment: So could you tell me what approach you went with? Does spliting your view along cells work? I am trying to use this but 1. I have lag (rare but does happen after a while, continuous scrolling ) and 2. Messy code

Answer (score 0):

If your `cell.clipsToBounds = NO` is working, but only the first time, I agree that the problem probably has to do with cell reuse. If you are overriding `-prepareForReuse`, you probably want to set `self.clipsToBounds = NO` in there. Then, in `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, set `clipsToBounds` to `YES` or `NO` every time as needed.

Comment: In preapreForReuse I remove these UIViews in the cells, else they get duplicated elsewhere in the UICollectionView when I scroll back and forward. Sideffects of removing is that the the extended views get cut off. Do you have a better way doing this, deleting duplicated cells?

Comment: It sounds like you're removing and re-adding the subview correctly. But are you resetting clipsToBounds correctly?

Comment: I tested and each time when I scroll to the left or right and the cell is out of the viewport, the extended part of the UIView in the cell is gone cause it starts at the part out of the viewport. That's the point. If I don't remove these UIViews from its superview (current cell) they got duplicated... Any solutions? I updated my question. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Zev the problem is that you empty the cell which gets enqueued, which leads to deletion of the extended part. A solution would be not to use reusable UICollectionViewCells, but that is bad coding style. So I splitted the items multiple times among cells.